# Atoi Function does not Convert Letters Properly

Tags: c, scanf, atoi

```
 printf("Enter a number or type 'Exit' to exit\n");

    long val = 0;
    int y = 3;

    scanf("%s", input);

    val = atoi(input); 


    if (val < y) {

       printf("Hey You!");

    }
    else {
        printf("Error, no such cell exists.\n");
    }
```

When the user types in '0', '1', or '2,' then "Hey You" is printed. However, when the user types in any letter such as 'y' or 'k' then "Hey You" is also printed. How do I make sure "Hey You" is only printed for values lower than 3 (which is y).

Comment: The `atoi` function returns `0` for conversion failure. If you want to distinguish `0` from `y` then you will have to use a different function, such as [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: Is `atoi()` required?

Comment: `n = scanf("%ld", &val)` with a `n == 1` check should be pretty straightforward

Comment: `atoi()` is a legacy function, from a time where error treatment was not so important as it is today.  It returns `0` on parsing errors, so you cannot distinguish the return value from the valid literal `0`.  If you need error control, then it is better to use `sscanf(3)` or `strtoi(3)` as has been suggested in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the C standard

> If  the  value  of  the  result  cannot  be  represented,  the
>   behaviour is undefined.

Any value can be returned. In your case this value is lower then 3. But it is not guaranteed.

`atoi` does not return any special value or does not set any error variable if the conversion cannot be performed

Answer (score -2):

Where have you defined `input`? Have you already allocated the memory for the string to be stored? If not, you may get a segmentation fault or `atoi` may return `0`.

According to the documentation on `atoi` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), if you have extra non-numerical symbols in the string, it will ignore them, and if there are none, it will return `0`.

Comment: `C++ != C` do not mix them, especially when you answer the questions.